# shrinking only the left margin

Tags: margins

I'm working with a document class that has already set the left margin to 1.5in and right to 1in. I want to change both margins to 1in.  I don't know how to alter the document class because I literally don't know where the `.cls` file is; it doesn't show up in finder (I remember having to do some kind of magic to get it to work when I first downloaded it). When I try `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` in my document, I get the error "the package geometry has already been loaded with options...".  I noticed that I'm able to alter both margins simultaneously with

```
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}
```

but obviously I only want to alter the left margin.

Comment: What is the name of the class?

Comment: Its something someone at my school wrote to format the dissertation to conform to the requirements set by the adminstrators

Answer (score 1):

Use the geometry package: much preferable.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[left=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I still get "the package geometry has ben loaded with options [] There has now been an attempt to load it with options [left=1in] Adding the global options:, left=1in to your \documentclass declaration may fix this."

Comment: If geometry is loaded by the class, you may type in the preamble: `\geometry{hmargin=1in}`.